# WCF expect header on every request

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I'm not sure how simple this is but I am trying to achieve a WCF Restful Service but whenever a method is hit I want it **"intercepted"**, This interception will check if header information exists identifying the user.

At the moment I am researching the best way to do this and have come across numerous mechanisms.

Search results before posting this comes up with **"WCF REST Starter Kit"** but my searching indicates this is abandoned!

Additionally, there is apparently something called a "RequestInterceptor" but not found a great deal on this either. I have come across the **"ServiceAuthorizationManager"** which I have had trouble with for a few days now (in the sense that it never gets called even though I set it the config)

```
<serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="SomeNamespace.MyAuthorizationManager,SomeNamespace" />
```

I have my service operational and one way I have this validation working is via inheritance. Not a great approach but hoping for someone to suggest a better way.

No restriction on version of .NET as this is a personal exercise I am working on :)

Comment: To be clear: Is the purpose of this interception to authenticate the caller (by checking your header) and then to grant or deny access based on the authenticated user identity?

Comment: Absolutely correct. I want to perform some checking as on initial log on I am thinking of sending a response back with a check digit (something along these lines) and every method is expecting this in the header which will evaluate whether its been tampered with. Early stages yet but is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I think the correct approach for WCF is to use a combination of ServiceAuthenticationManager and ServiceAuthorizationManager as shown in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715778/custom-wcf-authentication-with-system-servicemodel-serviceauthenticationmanager/3839743#3839743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to inspect incoming request Messages, check [Message Inspectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried that but I imagine whenever I make a request my custom IDispatchMessageInspector should fire right?

Comment: If the Service you are calling is using the appropiate behavior, yes

Comment: Maybe my config is wrong but I tried what you are saying and its not working for me. Tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7506438/1134076.

Comment: You sent me down the right path to enlightenment and lead me to this here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5266178/1134076. Solved the problem although need to decorate my services with a custom behavior. Not great but my god it works now after a week of pain! At least now making some progress.